# Merging DataFrames on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have a frame *moviegoers* that includes zip codes but not cities.

[image: Image of moviegoers output.]

I then redefined *moviegoers* to be *zipcodes* and changed the data type of *zip codes* to be a data frame instead of a series.

```
 zipcodes = pd.read_csv('NYC1-moviegoers.csv',dtype={'zip_code': object})
```

[image: Image of zipcodes output.]

I know the dataset URL I need is this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mafudge/datasets/master/zipcodes/free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv.

I defined a dataframe, *zip_codes*, to call the data from that dataset and change the dataset type from series to dataframe so its in the same format as the *zipcodes* dataframe.

[image: Image of zip_codes data frame output.]

I want to merge the dataframes so I can have the *movie goer* data. But, instead of *zipcodes*, I want to have the state abbreviation. This is where I am having issues.

The end goal is to count the number of movie goers per state. Example ideal output:

```
CA    116
MN     78
NY     60
TX     51
IL     50
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No where are you changing dataset type from series to dataframe. Every column of a pandas Dataframe is a pandas Series. Setting *object* means defining the data type of column as string type.

Answer (score 0):

I think need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` and then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for count:

```
print (zipcodes)
  zip_code
0    85711
1    94043
2    32067
3    43537
4    15213

s = zip_codes.set_index('Zipcode')['State']
df = zipcodes['zip_code'].map(s).value_counts().rename_axis('state').reset_index(name='count')
print (df.head())
  state  count
0    OH      1
1    CA      1
2    FL      1
3    AZ      1
4    PA      1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `merge` both datasets on *Zipcode* columns then run `groupby` for state counts.

```
# READ DATA FILES WITH RENAMING OF ZIP COLUMN IN FIRST
url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mafudge/datasets/master/zipcodes/free-zipcode-database-Primary.csv"

moviegoers = pd.read_csv('NYC1-moviegoers.csv', dtype={'zip_code': object}).rename(columns={'zip_code': 'Zipcode'})    
zipcodes = pd.read_csv(url, dtype={'Zipcode': object})

# MERGE ON COMMON FIELD
merged_df = pd.merge(moviegoers, zipcodes, on='Zipcode')

# AGGREGATE BY INDICATOR (STATE)
merged_df.groupby('State').size()

# ALTERNATIVE GROUP BY COUNT
merged_df.groupby('State')['Zipcode'].agg('count')
```